# SPARQLWrapper - Connecting RDFLib with Fuseki Server

Tags: sparql, jena, endpoint, fuseki

I am a newbie of SPARQL and Fuseki. I set up Fuseki Server with

```
fuseki-server --update --mem /address_act
```

to create a dataset.

And I have a graph containing many triples and then I want to add these triples into the dataset via SPARQLUPDATE. Here are the code to get triples into graph and try to save it to the dataset via Fuseki Server:

```
import requests
import rdflib
import re
from rdflib import ConjunctiveGraph, Graph, Literal, URIRef
from rdflib.plugins.stores import sparqlstore

query_endpoint = 'http://localhost:3030/address_act/query'
update_endpoint = 'http://localhost:3030/address_act/update'
store = sparqlstore.SPARQLUpdateStore()
store.open((update_endpoint, update_endpoint))

default_graph = URIRef('http://example.org/default-graph')
ng = Graph(store, identifier=default_graph)

g = Graph()
g1 = Graph()
for i in range(1,2):
    url = 'http://gnafld.net/address/?per_page=3&page=' + str(i)
    g.parse(url) 
    page = g.query("""SELECT ?subject
              WHERE {
                 ?subject a <http://gnafld.net/def/gnaf#Address>.
              }""")

    for row in page: 
        ad_info = requests.get(row.subject).content
        g1.parse(data=ad_info, format='turtle')
        #print('The number of triples in Graph: {}'.format(len(g1)))

ng.update(
u'INSERT DATA { %s }' % g1.serialize(format='turtle')
)
```

Besides, I have another way to do this using SPARQLWrapper:

```
import requests
import rdflib
import re
from rdflib import ConjunctiveGraph, Graph, Literal, URIRef
from rdflib.plugins.stores import sparqlstore
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper

query_endpoint = 'http://localhost:3030/address_act/query'
update_endpoint = 'http://localhost:3030/address_act/update'
store = sparqlstore.SPARQLUpdateStore()
store.open((update_endpoint, update_endpoint))

default_graph = URIRef('http://example.org/default-graph')
g = Graph()
g1 = Graph(identifier=default_graph)

for i in range(1,2):
    url = 'http://gnafld.net/address/?per_page=3&page=' + str(i)
    g.parse(url) 
    page = g.query("""SELECT ?subject
              WHERE {
                 ?subject a <http://gnafld.net/def/gnaf#Address>.
              }""")

    for row in page:
        ad_info = requests.get(row.subject).content
        g1.parse(data=ad_info, format='turtle')
        #print('The number of triples in Graph: {}'.format(len(g1)))

for s,p,o in g1:
    queryStringUpload = 'INSERT DATA {GRAPH <http://example.org/default-graph> {%s %s %s}}'  %(s,p,o)
    sparql = SPARQLWrapper('http://localhost:3030/address_act/update')
    sparql.setQuery(queryStringUpload)
    sparql.method = 'POST'
    sparql.query()
```

When I run the two above, the last sentence `ng.update(u'INSERT DATA { %s }' % g1.serialize(format='turtle'))` and  `sparql.query()` in the program causes the error. I am sure these triples have existed in the graph, but when do update, both give the error like:

```
QueryBadFormed: QueryBadFormed: a bad request has been sent to the endpoint, probably the sparql query is bad formed. 

Response:
b'Error 400: Lexical error at line 11, column 59.  Encountered: "\\\'" (39), after : "b"\n\n\nFuseki - version 3.7.0 (Build date: 2018-04-05T11:04:59+0000)\n'
```

and error like:

```
QueryBadFormed: QueryBadFormed: a bad request has been sent to the endpoint, probably the sparql query is bad formed. 

Response:
b'Error 400: Line 1, column 56: Unresolved prefixed name: http:\n\n\nFuseki - version 3.7.0 (Build date: 2018-04-05T11:04:59+0000)\n'
```

It seems that the SPARQL update operation does not work. Is there any grammar mistake so that the triples cannot be inserted?  Any idea how to solve this? Grateful for any effort.

Comment: Did you try a simple update query in the Web interface of Fuseki?

Comment: Did you check the query string which will be sent?

Comment: Yes, I tried a simple insert query from http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/, it shows :Error 400: SPARQL Query: No 'query=' parameter. So  I am wondering whether I need modify the configuration file probably...?

Comment: Can you show the config file?

Comment: and compare with [this](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-configuration.html)?

Comment: I have edited the question to show current config.ttl. Originally, the file is empty. Then I found the configuration description from https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-configuration.html and then add all of them to the config.ttl. Unfortunately, it still does not work.

Comment: Does `fuseki-server --config=PATH_TO_CONFIG_FILE` change anything?

Comment: Oh thanks, the simple update example works on the Fuseki UI now, but when adding the triples I need, it still returns the same error...

Comment: Which query does not work now? Or which part of the code?

Comment: The two ways to add address triples above, still have the same errors. The simple update example I mentioned is from the SPARQL Update documentation.

Comment: Check the following: store.open((update_endpoint, update_endpoint))

I believe the first parameter should be the query endpoint